# reference array using variable in Java

Tags: java, talend

I please bear with me, I have been using Java for 2 days and i've hit a bit of a hurdle.

I am using Talend to perform a count using the tMemorize and tJava components but this may be a question for a Java developer.  I have previously posted an issue with using this method within a joblet by my new issue is more Java related which can be viewed here: 
[using Joblets in talend with tMemorize and tJavaFlex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651501/using-joblets-in-talend-with-tmemorize-and-tjavaflex?noredirect=1#comment47468316_29651501)

I need to reference an array generated by the java code talend. I cannot reference this element directly because of an issue with using tJavaFlex within multiple joblets: Java renames joblets each time they are used.

It may be useful to understand how my code works in normal circumstances (excluding the use of joblets).

```
int counter = 1;

if (EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[0].equals(EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[1]))
{
counter++;
}
row3.counter = counter;
```

The `EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[0]` and `EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[1]` is what I need to reference.

To overcome this I have written the following code.

```
String string = currentComponent;
String[] parts = string.split("_");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String joblet = part1+'_'+part2;
String newrow = "EnquiryID_"+joblet+"_tMemorizeRows_1"

if (newrow[0].equals(newrow[1]))
{
counter++;
}
row3.counter = counter;
```

However I get the following error:

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String
```

I understand that the `newrow` variable is a string and I am using it to reference an array.  I have searched far and wide online for a resolve but I cannot fine one.  Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Here is the talend code that my code should reference.  I have taken it from the currentComponent that I am using to when it changes to one not in use directly.

```
                        currentComponent = "mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1";

                    // row1
                    // row1

                    if (execStat) {
                        runStat.updateStatOnConnection("row1" + iterateId,
                                1, 1);
                    }

                    for (int i_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1 = iRows_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1 - 1; i_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1 > 0; i_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1--) {
                        EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[i_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1] = EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[i_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1 - 1];
                    }
                    EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[0] = row1.EnquiryID;

                    mem_1_row2 = row1;

                    tos_count_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1++;

                    /**
                     * [mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1 main ] stop
                     */

                    /**
                     * [mem_1_tJavaFlex_1 main ] start
                     */

                    currentComponent = "mem_1_tJavaFlex_1";

                    // mem_1_row2
                    // mem_1_row2

                    if (execStat) {
                        runStat.updateStatOnConnection("mem_1_row2"
                                + iterateId, 1, 1);
                    }

                    mem_1_row3.QuoteID = mem_1_row2.QuoteID;
                    mem_1_row3.EnquiryID = mem_1_row2.EnquiryID;

                    if (EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[0]
                            .equals(EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[1])) {
                        rower++;
                    }
                    mem_1_row3.rower = rower;

                    tos_count_mem_1_tJavaFlex_1++;

                    /**
                     * [mem_1_tJavaFlex_1 main ] stop
                     */

                    /**
                     * [mem_1_tMap_1 main ] start
                     */

                    currentComponent = "mem_1_tMap_1";
```

Thank you to everyone who has helped so far.

Comment: Unfortunately making a String with the name of something that you want to reference does create a reference to that something. You just end up wtih a String with the name inside.

Comment: Hi @EvanKnowles,  Thank you for your response.  I understand this is the case, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: what you want you to compare??

Comment: What is the String `newrow` supposed to look up?  Are you trying to access a Map or a database?

Comment: Hello, I know I cannot use the newrow string in the array because it is not an array.  the tMemorize function in Talend stores the number of rows that you want to reference, in this case 2.  It is looking within a column containing reference ID's. So it will memorise row 1 and 2, then the java will compare them, if they are the same a count is performed, if they are not the count begins at 1. I know that I cannot use this reference in the array, is there a way this can be done? Thank you

Comment: Where does it store. Is there a variable or a call that must  be done? Right now `newrow` is just a `String` you declare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
if (newrow[0].equals(newrow[1]))
```

Tries to pick the first and second element of the array `newrow`. Unfortunately you declare `newrow` as

```
String newrow = "EnquiryID_"+joblet+"_tMemorizeRows_1"
```

which is not an `array` but a `String`. That syntax in the `if` will not work with a `String`. I am not sure what you are trying to do but that if check will not work.

EDIT:
If you are trying to pick up `char` from a string you need to use `charAt(index)`.

If you want to treat `newrow` as an array you have to declare it as such and pass appropriate elements to it.

EDIT 2: I think you are trying to pass the actual data in `joblet` to `newrow` in this:

```
String newrow = "EnquiryID_"+joblet+"_tMemorizeRows_1"
```

But what happens here is that everything is concatenated in one `String` so you need to figure out where the data you are looking for (`part[0]` and `part[1]` I assume) is present in that `String` so you can pull them out (basically what indices contain the values you are looking for).

An example of how newrow will look after that assignment:

```
"EnquiryID_part1_part2_tMemorizeRows_1"
```

So `"part1"` will start at index 10 and will end at index 14. I am just using `"part1"` here, but it would have whatever value is stored in `part1` variable.

If you can show us what you expect it to look like that would help.

Comment: Hi @CodeWhisperer, I am just digesting your comments. Thanks

Comment: Hello, so the array in my code: string[] is referencing an array from the currentComponet variable, talend assigns components to this variable when used. the string.split is splitting the name of by "_" and then putting it back together.  This is to get the name of the joblet that is being used. (Talend renames joblets but you can only modify it in 1 place). So if currentComponent is called "mem_1_tJavaFlex_1", which it is, my "Part 1" will be "mem" and part 2 = "1". This is then concatenated as "mem_1". Its for referencing back to the original array but I cant use it as an array. Thank you

Comment: @RiccoBalboa So what do you want logically to happen here: `newrow[0].equals(newrow[1]`. Just explain the logic of what is supposed to be compared. For example you have `mem_1` and what do you want to do with it further.

Comment: Hello The tMemorize function in Talend stores the number of rows that you want to reference, in this case 2. It is looking within a column containing reference ID's. So it will memorise row 1 and 2, then my java will compare them, if they are the same a count is performed, if they are not the count begins at 1. mem_1 is the name of the joblet in Talend. its like a reference that Talend uses, it uses this syntax "columnName_jobletName_componentName". Does this help?

Comment: So if `newrow` is `EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1` that means everything is ok? If it is `EnquiryID_mem_0_tMemorizeRows_1` its not?

Comment: Yeah, I have 2 arrays here, the one for `Part1` and `part 2` is not the one where the issue is. This section just returns the name of the array, the issue is that it returns the array as a string and not an array. The `newrow[0]` should return the contents of a row but i get an error because the talend code knows that `EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1[0]` is an array but my code is `"EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1"+[0]` which is a string with an element of an array. Java cant use this to reference the column. I need to find out how to use my string `newrow` to reference the [0] array.

Comment: Well then make it an array or extract the part you need from the string and assign it to the array, like I stated in my answer.

Comment: That's what I am trying to find out, I cannot alter the talend code.  How can I achieve this using my original code? I need the whole string because this references the array. I need the string to be used to refer back to the array but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with talend (understand: not at all). But it sounds like you have some sort of attribute of a generated class (say myGeneratedObject) and you want to access it by name.

In that case, you could do something like:

```
String newrow = "EnquiryID_"+joblet+"_tMemorizeRows_1"
Field field = myGeneratedObject.getClass().getField(newrow);
if (field.getClass().isArray()) {
    if(Array.get(field, 0).equals(Array.get(field, 1)) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

It all depends how you access that field really and where it's declared. But if it's an attribute of an object, then the code above should work, +/- contextual adjustments due to my lack of knowledge of the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. can I be very cheeky and ask what your code is doing please?  In terms of Talend, I can create a job that writes the Java in the background for the entire job, but I can also use a Java component to make further modifications/additions etc.  This can be good, and a lot of the support is suggested in using Java so i'm trying to deal with it a guess...  But in this particular situation, Talend assigns my columns that I am referencing to an array, to be able to perform my count I need to reference these arrays in my Java.  I will analyse your code, thank you.

Comment: Hi @mprivat  I got some errors unfortunately.         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Field cannot be resolved to a type
 myGeneratedObject cannot be resolved
 Array cannot be resolved
 Array cannot be resolved
 Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete BlockStatements
 counter cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You come up with a variable containing the expected name of the array that you get from Talend. So the code here finds the Field with the name you have in the generated code. Once it gets it, there's a condition to make sure it's truly an Array (you can skip that if you know in advance, which it sounds like you do). Then the second 'if' is the equivalent of 'if (newrow[0].equals(newrow[1]))' that you were trying to do

Comment: 'myGeneratedObject' was just an example. Show more code including the declaration of EnquiryID_mem_1_tMemorizeRows_1 and I'll show you how to get to it.

Comment: Hmm, i can try.  the code i have included is my own code but the code from talend is 3500 rows deep which I understand would be inconsiderate if I posted on here.  I will see if I can narrow this down.  I understand what you have written though and massively appreciate the time you have put into this question.  Thanks to everyone else too.

Comment: Hello  I have edited my original question with some code from talend but bot sure if it will help.  I understand what you have done now, I guess i need to know what I would assign myGeneratedObjest to.